# how to fade out the UIPageViewController after I finish looking at the last image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I am working on an app and I want to have an introduction when user first launches the app. So I set up a UIPageView of several UIImageViews so that when user opens the app at the first time, they can see these images of introduction. I want to do something like: When user reach the last image and then user swipe again in the direction of left, the image fades out and the real screen of the app shows. How can I do that? Because i don't know how to know user reaches the last one in the first time and then he swipes again, which is the second time, image fades out. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: you can store a value in NSUserDefaults to indicate the user has seen the introduction

Comment: What I mean is that when I reach the last image and try to swipe left again, no method will be called so I can't do the fade thing. @myte